# SQL Server replication drop vs truncate of target tables

Tags: sql-server, snapshot, database-replication

The sp_addarticle stored procedure, used to create publication articles in SQL Server speak, has a parameter @pre_creation_cmd through which dropping the table or truncating data at the target server can be specified for a snapshot. What circumstances are appropriate for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pre_creation_cmd accepts one of four values:

- NONE
- DELETE
- DROP
- TRUNCATE

**DELETE TABLE**

> Assume that your Published article
>   data is filtered and that the
>   corresponding table in the
>   Subscription receives data from other
>   sources, perhaps another Publication
>   for example. Using the DELETE
>   operation for this parameter would
>   delete "only" the data the meets the
>   criteria of the filter definition,
>   leaving the remaining data at the
>   Subscriber intact.

**TRUNCATE TABLE**

> Removes all rows from a table without
>   logging the individual row deletions.
>   TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the
>   DELETE statement with no WHERE clause;
>   however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and
>   uses fewer system and transaction log
>   resources.

**DROP TABLE**

> Removes one or more table definitions
>   and all data, indexes, triggers,
>   constraints, and permission
>   specifications for those tables.

Comment: Thanks John, what circumstance would make one option more desirable over the other? Assuming there is a practical difference, which is why I ask.

Comment: TRUNCATE for example is considered to be a superior performing operation than DELETE. You also cannot perform a TRUNCATE operation on a table with foreign key references. Conversely, neither DELETE nor TRUNCATE will remove objects associated with the table such as indexes, which the DROP operation will do.

Comment: If I understand correctly in terms of replication if one has a table with no foreign key references use the TRUNCATE because it performs much better. Otherwise we delete data and live with the decreased performance. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you go with the Replication default which is DROP, unless you have a specific need to do otherwise.

Comment: What about `'NONE'`?